# What is $K^n$ when $K$ is a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, field-theory, terminology

[image]

where I am not fully satisfied that $K^n$ is a field, rather $n$ pieces of fields under cartesian product such that $K\times K \times K \times \dots \times K$ where $n$ pieces of $K$. Also $K^n$ contains $n$-length tuples where each parameter in $K$. How is $K^n$ usually defined?

Comment: As you've noted, $K^n$ is $n$-tuples of elements in $K$, and this is not a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a field. As a ring, it is not even an integral domain, since $(0,1,\ldots)\cdot (1,0,\ldots)=0$. As a set, it consists of $n$-length tuples of elements of $K$.

Depending on your setting, you may want to view $K^n$ as an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space or an $n$-dimensional $K$-algebra.

In algebraic geometry,  thinking of it as $n$-length tuples is sufficient, since:

- You don't really use the ring/group structure of $K^n$, and
- As a ring $K^n$ has special points ($0$, $1$ etc). In algebraic geometry, you're not interested in these. As such, it is common notation to denote this set by $\mathbb A_K^n$ to differentiate it from the other interpretations of $K^n$.

Comment: Can you describe the $n$-dimensional $K$-algebra? This [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)?

Comment: I'm no algebraic geometer, but I've seen people write ${\bf A}^n$ to mean the scheme (as opposed to the set $n$-tuples).

Comment: @tomasz I'm also no algebraic geometer.  On page 1 of Hartshorne it's defined in this way, and called "affine $n$ space over $K$". In chapter $2$, it is indeed used to refer to the scheme.